# RAM usage increased while large file is read, how to overcome this?

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

Wrote a python code to decrypt a file of 15+ GB size. As soon as it executes the below code, RAM usage went high, as I am reading file and decrypting it.

```
with open(file1, 'rb') as fileRef:
    result = gpg.decrypt_file(fileRef, passphrase=passphrase_value,output=target_file)
```

Can somebody suggest me? I tried exploring various ways to decrypt the file but could not find any.

Comment: If you're reading the whole file, there is no going around this. It'll take memory to read this file you can't help it.

Comment: Can you rework your code to decrypt the file in chunks, writing each chunk to disc when it is decrypted and clearing memory ready for the next chunk?

Comment: @rossum, I am not sure how decryption will work in case of processing chunk files. In some of the cases like zip, the signature is written at the end of file

Comment: You could either directly access the end of the file if your operating system allows, or else read the file through twice, once to read the signature and once again to do the decryption.